# Get serial number of hard disk in java by Mac computer?

Tags: java, macos

I'm building a simple class in Java that return the serial number of disk of computer. So this is the code:

```
package utility;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class TestReadSerialNumber {
  private TestReadSerialNumber() {  }

  public static String getSerialNumber(String drive) {
  String result = "";
    try {
      File file = File.createTempFile("realhowto",".vbs");
      file.deleteOnExit();
      FileWriter fw = new java.io.FileWriter(file);

      String vbs = "Set objFSO = CreateObject(\"Scripting.FileSystemObject\")\n"
                  +"Set colDrives = objFSO.Drives\n"
                  +"Set objDrive = colDrives.item(\"" + drive + "\")\n"
                  +"Wscript.Echo objDrive.SerialNumber";  // see note
      fw.write(vbs);
      fw.close();
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cscript //NoLogo " + file.getPath());
      BufferedReader input =
        new BufferedReader
          (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
      String line;
      while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
         result += line;
      }
      input.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result.trim();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    String sn = TestReadSerialNumber.getSerialNumber("C");
    System.out.println(sn);}
}
```

Now if I try to start this code from a Windows, I have the correct result. If I try to start this code on a Mac Computer, I don't have never string from getSerialNumber method.

I think that the problem is in the System Operation and my code is compatible only with Windows and not with Mac. 
Then, how can I get the serial number by Mac computer ?

Comment: Did you search your question on google ? I would say your current solution is Windows specific (cscript), so you need to implement a Mac version too

Comment: My solution is to Windows and Mac, in fact I have used Java as language of program

Comment: You have used `Java` to generate a script `vbs` and execute it on the OS using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` (That part is compatible). But once you exec a code on the `Runtime`, you ask the OS to do the job, from there, you loose the portability of `Java`...

Comment: Here, for instance, your script is using [`FileSystemObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/z9ty6h50%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). A Windows functionnality.

Comment: Ok, but how can I modify my method or implements another method to get a serial number of drive letter ?

Comment: Are you expecting me to convert your script/logic to work on MAC? That's not that easy, start by searching a working solution on MAC, then you will need to find how to execute one or the other based on the system OS. I am not going to do it for you. This is not a small implementation.

Comment: No I'm not an expert of Mac system